# What is adapter object pattern?

Tags: java, collections

I was reading advantages of collection framework,I found a statement that "the Java Collections Framework frees you from writing adapter objects or conversion code to connect APIs."I am unable to understand this......

[a link] http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/intro/

I googled and found some adapter pattern and other stuff.........but I want to know about "adapter object" .

can any one explain......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I have a crude example. Say you have to work with 2 APIs - one of them is related to mobiles and the other to books. Say the mobile API developer gives you this API:

```
public class MobileList {
    private Mobile[] mobiles;
    //other fields

    public void addMobileToList(Mobile mobile) {
        //some code to add mobile
    }

    public void getMobileAtIndex(int index) {
        return mobiles[index];
    }

    //maybe other methods
}
```

And say the books API developer gives you this API:

```
public class BookList {
    private Book[] books;
    //other fields

    public void addBook(Book book) {
       //some code to add book
    }

    public Book[] getAllBooks() {
        return books;
    }

}
```

Now if your piece of code works only on the following 'products' interface:

```
interface Products {
    void add(Product product);
    Product get(int index);
}
```

you'd have to write following 'adapter' objects that implement your required interface:

```
class MobileListAdapter implements Products {
    private MobileList mobileList;

    public void add(Product mobile) {
        mobileList.addMobileToList(mobile);
    }

    public Product get(int index) {
        return mobileList.getMobileAtIndex(index);
    }
}

class BookListAdapter implements Products {
    private BookList bookList;

    public void add(Product book) {
        bookList.add(book);
    }

    public Product get(int index) {
        return bookList.getAllBooks()[index];
    }
}
```

Note that each such `Product` API can have various methods and various method *names* as well. If your code is expecting to work only on the `Products` interface, you'd have to write such 'adapters' for every new `Product` that came in.

That's where Java collections help (`java.util.List` for this specific example). With Java's `List` interface, the developers can simply give out `List<Mobile>` and `List<Book>` and you can simply call `get(index)` or `add(product)` on these `List`s without requiring any adapter classes. This is because now the `MobileList` and `BookList` have common set of method names and behaviors. I think this is what is meant in the documentation where it says

> By facilitating interoperability among unrelated APIs

the unrelated APIs in this case were `MobileList` and `BookList`.

Answer (score 1):

Adapter pattern is used to when you want two different classes with incompatible interfaces to work together.See this for example http://javapapers.com/design-patterns/adapter-pattern/